# How do I keep rounded corners consistent in InDesign when drawing a stroke?

Tags: adobe-indesign, stroke

I'm working on a diagram where I want my strokes corners to be rounded and keep consistent. However, when I draw a stroke, the measure doesn't seem to apply to all corners equally. I didn't scale this stroke in any way, just clicked and held shift to keep lines straight.

Am I missing something? How do I draw a stroke with consistent rounded corners?

[image: Problem example.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each path *segment* needs to be a *minimum* of your rounding value times 2 in length.

InDesign takes the rounding value and applies it to each end of every path segment. That means for 1p0 rounding on a horizontal path, InDesign assigns 1p0 to both the left and right end of the segment. Meaning the minimum path segment length, to retain the 1p0 rounding, is a 2p0 segment.

Shorter segments will use the maximum rounding possible. If the segment is not 2 picas long and rounding is set a 1p0, then instead of using 1p0 for the rounding *on each end of that segment*, InDesign will use the segment length/2 for rounding. This results in inconsistent rounding.

InDesign does try and favor the rounding value, So if a corner has a single shorter side segment but it's above the rounding value, InDesign will round one corner at the value, then "short" the other corner the remaining length of the segment.

End anchors assume they need the same 1p0 of the rounding value even if there is no rounding on the end anchors. So a 0p6 long segment really only allows for a maximum of 0p3 for rounding at each end.

Comment: Oh geez, I thought my rulers were in inches. Thank you!

Comment: Been there :) Done that :) .... many times.... Glad I could help :)